# Cannot call Injected [through dependency injection] object method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to call the SendQueuedEmailsToRecipients method from a Maintenance class. My understanding is that because the Maintenance class depends on the SendQueuedEmailsToRecipients method (which is in a different namespace) then I need to DI the method into the Maintenance class. Is this correct? - I am having trouble doing this.

I am unsure if I am going about this the right way. (Still learning Csharp and ASP.NET core).  I do not really know where to call up IBulkEmailQueue.  Sorry- I am a bit lost here but am trying to understand.

My code is:
root/BLL/MaintenanceBLL/Maintenance.cs

```
public class Maintenance : IMaintenance
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public Maintenance(ApplicationDbContext Context)
    {
        _context = Context;
    }
    //-------------------**MY DI ATTEMPT**
    private readonly BulkEmailQueue _bulkEmailQueue;

    public Maintenance(BulkEmailQueue BulkEmailQueue)
    {
        _bulkEmailQueue = BulkEmailQueue;
    }
    //-------------
    public void DoMaintenance()
    {
        //Parse Maintenance table and action those items
        //where Active=True and ActionDate has pass
        //==================================
        //Retrieve list of rows in Maintenance table
        var maintenances = _context.Maintenance;
        foreach (Models.Maintenance m in maintenances)
        {
            switch (m.Subject)
            {
                case "Send Queued Emails":
                    if (m.ActionDateTime <= DateTime.Now)
                    {
                        //BulkEmailQueue bulkEmailQueue = new BulkEmailQueue();//Create new instance 
                        //BulkEmailQueue.SendQueuedEmailsToRecipients();

                        _bulkEmailQueue.SendQueuedEmailsToRecipients();  **ERROR DISPLAYS ON THIS LINE**. System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

                        m.ActionDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15);
                        m.LastActionDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    // code block
                    break;
            }
        }
```

My root/startup contains:

```
       services.AddTransient<IMaintenance, Maintenance>();
       services.AddTransient<IBulkEmailQueue, BulkEmailQueue>();
```

My root/Services/IBulkEmailQueue.cs contains

```
    public interface IBulkEmailQueue
     {
       public void SendQueuedEmailsToRecipients();
       public void DeleteRecord();
       public void AddToQueue();
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have two constructors for your `Maintenance` class? Which one will be called?

Comment: are we assuming `ApplicationDbContext` is also set correctly in startup file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is all fine except that Only one constructor shall be required to inject the dependency `IMaintenance` and `ApplicationDbContext`. Also, make sure that `ApplicationDbContext` is also setup in the startup.cs as done for `IMaintenance` and  `IBulkEmailQueue`

The MODIFIED code goes as below.

```
public class Maintenance : IMaintenance
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    private readonly IBulkEmailQueue _bulkEmailQueue; // this should be interface

    public Maintenance(ApplicationDbContext Context,IBulkEmailQueue BulkEmailQueue)
    {
        _context = Context;
        _bulkEmailQueue = BulkEmailQueue;
    }
    //-------------------**MY DI ATTEMPT**
    public void DoMaintenance()
    {
    //Parse Maintenance table and action those items
    //where Active=True and ActionDate has pass
    //==================================
    //Retrieve list of rows in Maintenance table
    var maintenances = _context.Maintenance;
    foreach (Models.Maintenance m in maintenances)
    {
        switch (m.Subject)
        {
            case "Send Queued Emails":
                if (m.ActionDateTime <= DateTime.Now)
                {
                    _bulkEmailQueue.SendQueuedEmailsToRecipients();  **NO ERROR SHALL DISPLAY ON THIS LINE**. 

                    m.ActionDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15);
                    m.LastActionDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                }
                break;
            default:
                // code block
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you Ajeet.  Much appreciated.  I am trying to learn C# and ASP.NET core Razor pages but I come from an ASP.NET web forms and VBA background.  It is a bit of an uphill challenge!!!  Thanks again.